# Use data from a sibling state in Redux

Tags: redux

Let's say I got the following state definition

```
export const IFooState {
   settings: ISettingsState;
   somedata: ISomedataState;
};
```

`ISomedataState`in turn has a property `visible` (it might as well be much deeper inside the state hierarchy). The value of `visible` however comes from settings, i.e. `ISettingsState`. Now how do I get my hands on the current value in order to be able to set `visible` inside `ISomedataState`?

Of course, you might argue that I could listen for the action which sets the flag in 'settings' and update the value(s) in 'data' at the same time, but what if my action demands creating a new object, for example? I don't have the current value at that point in time.

At the moment I work around that problem by intercepting the action in the root state and then adding the value for `visible` to the action payload, but that feels hacky.

What is the recommended approach?

Comment: Now how do I get my hands on the current value?. where?. How do you get the value where? In the component, in an action, in the reducer, in the view?

Comment: Inside of `ISomedataState`, of course. Let's say I got 2 actions, `SET_VISIBLE` and `NEW_ITEM`. The former is supposed to hide/show all items somewhere inside `ISomedataState`, the latter creates a new item in `ISomedataState`. Now I dispatch `SET_VISIBLE` with payload `true`, all items show up. I then create a new item issueing `NEW_ITEM` which has its visible flag set to an initial value which may happen to be `false`. So now all items except the new one show up. What I'd like to do is, to provide the actual value for `visible` so that all items are either shown or hidden, but not mixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of TypeScript is obfuscating things a bit, but I think you're basically asking this question from the Redux FAQ: [Redux FAQ: Reducers](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/Reducers.html#reducers-share-state).

Comment: Exactly, that's where I arrived at eventually. I decided to duplicate the visibility indicator in the data state because it made perfect sense and I didn't want to sacrifice `combineReducers` in favor of forwarding actions in a root state myself.